# Excel: Working around sorting tables by date, with empty rows in the range

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, cell

I am working on a model that requires me to sort data in a range by date, before copying the data into a different template on another sheet. Every row has a formula that pulls data from Bloomberg, so even if the cell looks empty, excel recognizes that there is content in the cell. Sorting the date column as it is does not work, as excel wont recognize the data that Bloomberg pulls as a date, so it would be sorted from A to Z, which scrambles the dates instead.

To work around this, I inserted and adjacent column with the formula (using cell A1 as an example) "=(A1+0)" that then allows the column to be sorted from new to old. The problem here is that if cell A1 does not display a date (in other words, it appears empty yet the cell contains a formula that leaves the cell looking empty if no date is pulled) it returns a #VALUE! error and sorting new to old would put the errors at the top (Thank you Excel for this fantastic feature, btw).

To work around this new issue, I replaced the above formula in the cell with "=IFERROR(A1+0,1)" which gives me the date 1/1/1900. Fine, now the data is sorted in the manner I want it, but I have a bunch of ancient dates that just make my end product look ugly.

I have two questions, first; how can I use VBA to delete the data in the cells where the date equals 1 (which shows the date 1/1/1900), and only those cells? Or, alternatively, only copying the rows above the cell that contains 1/1/1900.  This is a relatively small amount of cells that would be affected by this, 40 at most.

Second; is there a different way of sorting the data using VBA that I am missing, that might be more efficient?

Comment: I dont see why `=(A1+0)` results in error. Anyway. what if you try `=IFERROR(A1+0, "")` ?

Comment: If the formula in cell A1 does not pull a date it is treated as text by excel. Apologies that I wasn't more clear on that cell one is not actually empty, it just doesn't pull a date from Bloomberg due to a lack of a Cusip in a different cell. 

The "IFERROR" formula works in cleaning the look up, however, when I sort the column fron New to Old, it puts the blank results first. This creates an issue of having X amounts of "empty" rows at the top.

Thank you for your assistance, i will edit the question to clarify the issue with "A1"

Comment: Ok we can write a mcro to sort the range correctly at once. what is the range you want to sort and by which column?

Comment: Thank you. The range is from B3:P40, with row 2 being the headers, and the column to be sorted is column H

Comment: So column H is basically date strings (apart the errors)? Is the format consistent? what format are they?

Comment: Correct. Column H is formatted as a short date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this macro, I tried to test it with as many anomalies as possible.

```
Sub SortByDateColumnH()
    Dim r As Range: Set r = Sheet1.Range("B3:P40")
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In r.Columns(7).Cells
        If IsError(cel.Value) Then
            cel.Value = 0
        ElseIf Not IsDate(cel.Value) Then
            cel.Value = 0
        Else
            cel.Value = CLng(cel.Value)
        End If
    Next

    r.Columns(7).NumberFormat = "0"
    r.Sort Key1:=r.Cells(1, 7), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

    For Each cel In r.Columns(7).Cells
        If cel.Value < 100 Then cel.ClearContents
    Next
    r.Columns(7).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy" '<-- set the format to your preference

    'r.Copy Destination:=someDestination ' you can copy the range by code if needed
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, the macro you provided works great. For some inexplicable reason another, unrelated macro stopped working, so I'm going to go home and bang my head against the wall and try again Monday. Have a good weekend!